# Print preview a html table without header and footer of application

Tags: javascript, php, symfony-2.1

Hi I have a situation where I want to show a button to user to Suppose like:

"Print" on click this button I want to show print preview to user that is a html table which I want to print. But I do not want header and footer that is using my application to all pages to show in this print preview to user.

So how can I make this possible to printout a html page without header and footer only content part.

Please help me I have tried many solutions for this but did not get worked anymore. I am using php scripting language(Symfony2 framework)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
 @media print
 {
  #header{
   display:none;
  }
 #footer{
   display:none;
 }
</style>
```

This will make your header and footer invisible at print preview or printing time.

Answer (score 0):

In you css, add the classes and specify this class for the container element of the header and footer which has to be hide while printing.

```
@media print
{    
    .print
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide header and footer when you are printing.

```
    <html>
    <script>
    function print1(){
    document.getElementById("header").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("footer").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("print").style.display="none";
    window.print(); 
    }
    </script>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="print1()" id="print" value="print">
    </html>
```